# Angular 5 XSRF Token

Tags: angular, model-view-controller, csrf, x-xsrf-token

Angular 5 httpclient by default provides support for CSRF.
However, not sure how to turn this feature on.

Is it by,

1. Adding create cookie in Global.asax in my Asp.Net MVC server side code?
2. Adding "@Html.AntiForgeryToken()" in the index.cshtml page and reading it in my API controller?

Thank you.

Comment: It is by 2. Add the @Html.AntiForgeryToken method to the MVC view. Add ValidateAntiForgeryToken on the MVC action or controller. See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages

Comment: This solution did not work for me. Because, in our application,
1. I added @Html.AntiForgery token to the index.cshtml and then entire application is written in Angular 5 pages.
2. From the Angular services I call web api URL on a different server. So validate method, though it gets the token, it cannot validate it.